# Referring to a column in the first query from the second query in T-SQL UNION

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, union, aggregate

I have two SELECT statements that are UNIONed, as in the pseudo code below

```
SELECT A.InvoiceNumber, A.itemCode, A.itemDescription, A.Cost
FROM someTable A
UNION
SELECT InvoiceNumberFromSomeTable, B.itemCode, B.itemDescription, ***IwantTheSumOfAllCostsInTheFirstQueryForThisInvoiceNumber*** as Cost
FROM yetAnotherTable B
```

The expected result is

```
InvoiceNumber    itemCode         itemDescription                           Cost
I001             A000001          This is Item01 From SomeTable             15
I001             A000002          This is Item02 From SomeTable             16
I001             Total            This is Total From YetAnotherTable        31
I002             A000001          This is Item01 From SomeTable             25
I002             B000002          This is Item99 From SomeTable             26
I002             Total            This is Total From YetAnotherTable        51
```

In my case, the second query will always return one row and the Cost value should be the sum of all the Cost Values in first query.

How can one accomplish this? I've tried every approach I'm familiar with, but couldn't make it work. Please help and Thank you SOF community.

EDIT: I forgot to add the invoice number column. The totalling should happen for each invoice. Apologies for not adding this earlier.

Comment: So, for all rows in table A, you want a single row that gives you the sum of the cost?

Comment: What is the link between the 2 tables? This smells like a JOIN...

Comment: For each invoicenumber in table A, I need a row that totals the cost and gets the itemCode and itemDescription from table B. The invoiceNumber in the Total Row should come from table A because, such a column is not available in table B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to SUM as an extra column

```
SELECT
    A.itemCode, A.itemDescription, A.Cost,
    SUM(A.Cost) OVER () AS SumCostA
FROM someTable A
UNION
SELECT B.itemCode, B.itemDescription,
    Whatever1, Whatever2 --NULLs?
FROM yetAnotherTable B
```

It doesn't that much sense to have yetAnotherTable itemCode and itemDescription related to data from another table. What about Cost and Sum(Cost) from yetAnotherTable?

Is yetAnotherTable parent or category table? If so, a JOIN (no UNION) would make more sense

Edit, after update

```
SELECT
    A.InvoiceNumber, A.itemCode, A.itemDescription, A.Cost,
    SUM(A.Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY A.InvoiceNumber) AS SumCostAPerInvoice
FROM someTable A
UNION
SELECT InvoiceNumberFromSomeTable, B.itemCode, B.itemDescription,
    Whatever1, Whatever2 --NULLs?
FROM yetAnotherTable B
```

Comment: @gbn, that is a great suggestion, +1 from me as well; but I failed to add some details relevant to the question earlier and now I've added it. Thank you.

Comment: @FMFF: updated to calc SUM per Invoice as extra column. You need to describe what relevance yetAnotherTable and the UNION have. Please read my narrative, not just my SQL code

Comment: yetAnotherTable is a master or parent table, whose values don't change. I only need the description from the parent table (TOTAL etc) and the Cost would be calculated as mentioned. They don't have any  column that can act as a JOINing element. Thank you very much your time again.

Comment: @FMFF: Since you've added InvoiceNumber, it can't be done anyway. Not least, what if you have 3 invoices from A and 5 from B? How can you reconcile it? You need a separate column. Unless InvoiceNumber is the common field: then you can left join and get zeros from A correctly...

Comment: Hi gbn, only Total row's description comes from table B. InvoiceNumber, the summation of the cost are w.r.t table A.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, itemCode, itemDescription, Cost 
FROM 
(
    SELECT A.InvoiceNumber, A.itemCode, A.itemDescription, A.Cost, 1 dummy
    FROM someTable A
    UNION
    SELECT A.InvoiceNumber, 'Sub total', B.itemDescription, SUM(A.Cost), 2
    FROM yetAnotherTable B
    JOIN someTabel A ON A.InvoiceNumber = B.InvoiceNumberFromSomeTable
    GROUP BY A.InvoiceNumber, B.itemDescription
) a
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber,dummy
```

You should also try this. Although it will not give you the itemdescription from your second table

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx